# Queries work in XAMPP but not my LAMP Stack in AWS cloud

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, xampp, lamp

This is just a test case I wrote but my main question is my whole
application works locally connect to MySQL and return a couple thousand
records I turn error reporting on EALL for the page and I don't get any error all I actual get for output of this test case is Number Number Number Number Number five times which doesn't make any sense as I am grabbing one row
by primary key in this example. Any way I am new at PHP so any reference
for going from XAMPP to lamp would be appreciated. URL is http://prestigeworldwide.me/game/

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "Mypass";
$dbname = "test";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sqltest = sprintf("SELECT num, num2 FROM mytest WHERE num = 2");

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$resulttest = mysqli_query($conn, $sqltest);

foreach($resulttest as $row){
    echo("Number".$row['num'].$row['num2']);
}

mysqli_close($conn);;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use PDO. 
[Take a look here.](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059)

```
   $dbtype     = "mysql";
   $dbhost     = "localhost";
   $dbname     = "*****";
   $dbuser     = "*****";
   $dbpass     = "*****";

    try{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname; charset=utf8", $dbuser,$dbpass);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 } catch (PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
 }
$sql = "SELECT num, num2 FROM mytest WHERE num = '2'";
$q = $conn->query($sql);

while ($r = $q -> fetch()):
  echo "Number" . $r['num'] . $r['num2']);
endwhile;
```

Comment: Thank you the rest of MySQL code is procedural so I can give it a try but was looking for more of a quick fix on why it who work in xampp and not lamp.